# Method does not override method from its superclass - Action buttons within a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Method does not override method from its superclass in android when trying to add action buttons from within a fragment.

```
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater=getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function in a fragment requires a second parameter of type `MenuInflator`.

This function is the correct way to do it as per [this article](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/).

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastFragment, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`
inside `onCreateView`